# validate a field in the viemodel before submit mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a viewModel that implements custom validators:

```
 public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    #region country
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
    public ConfigurationParamValue CountryParam { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region civilty
    [CivilityValidator(DependantField = "CivilityParam", Category = "Category", IsLocal = "IsLocal")]
    public int Civility { get; set; }
    public ConfigurationParamValue CivilityParam { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Civilities { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region fistname
    [FirstNameValidator(DependantField = "FirstNameParam", Category = "Category", IsLocal = "IsLocal")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public ConfigurationParamValue?FirstNameParam { get; set; }
    #endregion
```

}

this a the validator of firstName:

```
 public class FirstNameValidator : BaseValidator,IClientValidatable
{
    private readonly IRegistrationConfiguration _registrationConfiguration;
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string IsLocal { get; set; }
    public string DependantField { get;set; }
    public FirstNameValidator()
    {
        _registrationConfiguration = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IRegistrationConfiguration>();

    }
    public FirstNameValidator(IRegistrationConfiguration registrationConfiguration, IVpSpeedResourceProvider resourceProvider, IMemberContext memberContext)
    {
        _registrationConfiguration = registrationConfiguration;
        ResourceProvider = resourceProvider;
        MemberContext = memberContext;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        object dependantPropertyValue=null;
        string categoryPropertyValue = string.Empty;
        bool isLocalPropertyValue = false;
        if (validationContext != null)
        {
            if (DependantField != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo dependantProperty = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType()
                    .GetProperty(DependantField);

                dependantPropertyValue = dependantProperty
                                           .GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
            }

            PropertyInfo categoryProperty = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType()
                .GetProperty(Category);

           categoryPropertyValue = (string)categoryProperty
                                      .GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

           PropertyInfo isLocalProperty = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType()
               .GetProperty(IsLocal);

           isLocalPropertyValue = (bool)isLocalProperty
                                     .GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        }


            if (value == null)
            {
                if(dependantPropertyValue != null && !((ConfigurationParamValue)dependantPropertyValue == ConfigurationParamValue.IsMandatory))
                    return ValidationResult.Success;
                return new ValidationResult(GetResource(isLocalPropertyValue, categoryPropertyValue, Constantes.FirstNameEmptyError));
            }
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
                    return new ValidationResult(GetResource(isLocalPropertyValue, categoryPropertyValue, Constantes.FirstNameEmptyError));
                if (value.ToString().Length < _registrationConfiguration.FirstNameFieldMinLength)
                    return new ValidationResult(GetResource(isLocalPropertyValue, categoryPropertyValue, Constantes.FirstNameMinLengthError));
                if (value.ToString().Length > _registrationConfiguration.FirstNameFieldMaxLength)
                    return new ValidationResult(GetResource(isLocalPropertyValue, categoryPropertyValue, Constantes.FirstNameMaxLengthError));
            }

         return ValidationResult.Success;

    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata,
                            ControllerContext context)
    {

        var viewModel = (RegistrationViewModel)context.Controller.ViewData.Model;
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("min", _registrationConfiguration.FirstNameFieldMinLength);
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("max", _registrationConfiguration.FirstNameFieldMaxLength);
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("mandatory", (viewModel.FirstNameParam == ConfigurationParamValue.IsMandatory ? true : false));
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("emptyerror", GetResource(viewModel.IsLocal, viewModel.Category, Constantes.FirstNameEmptyError));
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("minerror", GetResource(viewModel.IsLocal, viewModel.Category, Constantes.FirstNameMinLengthError));
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("maxerror", GetResource(viewModel.IsLocal, viewModel.Category, Constantes.FirstNameMaxLengthError));
        rule.ValidationType = "firstnamevalidator";
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

when i create my viewmodel, i read param from querystring :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
   RegistrationViewModel ViewModel=new RegistrationViewModel();
  var firstName = Request.QueryString["FirstName"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName))
            {
                VieWmodel.FirstName = firstName;
            }
  return View(ViewModel);}
```

So i need  only validate the property FirstName before return view, how can i do that??

Comment: i would like to do this in code c#, if the firstname is valid, i keep the value else firstname=string.empty

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do in this instance:  (W/ jquery and unobtrusive validation)

Since I dont see your view, I made a name up for your form:

Edid: If you only wanting to validate a single field, pass the ID before.valid()

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#CreateForm").submit(function (e) {
            if (!$("#FirstName").valid()) {
                alert('An Error has been detected on the page. Please correct and resubmit.');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    </script>
```

This will call your validation which is done in C# and pass the result back to your view.

Comment: i would like to do this in code c#, if the firstname is valid, i keep the value else firstname=string.empty

Comment: i will validate all form, i need to validate only the field firstname

Comment: Pass the field you need to validate into .valid()...See Edits.